# Not able to read value of DHT11

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, sensors

I am using python to get value of humidity and temperature by using DHT11 sensor on Raspberry Pi, following is the code am using:

```
import sys
import Adafruit_DHT

while True:

    humidity, temperature = Adafruit_DHT.read_retry(11, 4)

    print 'Temp: {0:0.1f} C  Humidity: {1:0.1f} %'.format(temperature, humidity)
```

Can anyone help me ? Am confused, if there is the mistake in code or something

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: Problem is, the value printed is 'None', 'None'
for both, Temperature and Humidity

Comment: Did you run it with permissions to use the GPIO (right group or `sudo`)?

Comment: Yes, am using every command with sudo

Comment: which Python version are you using? It seems that the code is alright. Have you checked that your sensor is working correctly?

Comment: Python2.7.3
Yes, sensor is working correctly
I have checked the same sensor on Arduino, its giving values